# How can I keep a graphics device open in R batch mode?

Tags: r, user-interface, batch-processing, rscript

I am trying to use the `DataEntry` package in R batch mode in Windows. Specifically I am using

```
Rscript -e "DataEntry::DataEntry()"
```

The code works, but once the GUI for the form opens, it closes immediately and R exits. I have noticed similar behaviour in the past, whilst trying to show plots using the R graphics device in batch mode.

I did a little searching online and found something that actually suspends complete execution of the script, which I implemented thus:

```
Rscript -e "DataEntry::DataEntry(); readLines(file('stdin'))"
```

It halted the execution alright and also displayed the expected window, but the GUI never completely loads and thus is non-operable.

The `DataEntry` package works with `RGtk2`, `gWidgets2RGtk2` and `gWidgets2`.